# Form not showing in designer, but all controls are

Tags: c#

I was testing out a skin theme on an application of mine, and decided i didnt like it. I clicked the theme control and deleted it from the application, and my computer crashed.

now, visual studio shows my tab control and all tabs, and all internal controls, but the form title bar and border are missing.. I cant resize, move, or close the application.

[image]
I was able to get around this at runtime by adding

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

to the Load method, but I want it fixed the right way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should restore the form file(s) from source control. The component that applied the theme was likely invasive in that it didn't just change runtime rendering behavior or look, it actively changed properties on the form. There is likely no easy way to restore the old values except to go back to the previous version in version control.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this project wasn't stored in a repository, so unfortunately unless this is secretly built into visual studio, that's not an easy option

Comment: No, there is nothing built into Visual Studio. You should get into the habit of always using version control :)

Comment: Duly noted. I was looking into SVN, wish I had gotten it all set up before this.

Answer (score 0):

So, in this situation, what I ended up doing was adding a new Form to the solution, selecting the tab-control object, and copy/pasting it to the new form. This kept all the properties the same, except the event handlers. I had to move all the methods from the .cs file to the new form, and then reset all my events on various controls. Finally, I set the new form as the opening form and removed the original [broken] form from the project.